# Как создать плеер на странице Javascript?

Tags: javascript, плеер

Помогите, плз, нужен плеер (чтоб музон запускать со страницы) на Javascript, работу сдавать на днях, а вот он никак не выходит...

Comment: А что именно нужно? Реализовать плеер на javascript или подсказать, как это сделать?
Есть много flash проигрывателей без интерфейса для воспроизведения аудио и управляемых командами на js. Можно даже готовый найти с js и отредактировать стили. Я такой когда-то делал. Опишите конкретнее, что вы хотите узнать! Если ищите работника, то лучше на фрилансе, за бесплатно никто не будет, к тому же, здесь тематика данного сервиса другая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/):

> SoundManager 2 позволяет проще проигрывать аудио с помощью JavaScript. Использование HTML5 и Flash обеспечивает надежное звучание через кросс-платформенный API.

```
soundManager.url = '/path/to/sm2-flash-movies/';
soundManager.useFlashBlock = false;

soundManager.onload = function() {
    soundManager.createSound('helloWorld','/path/to/hello-world.mp3');
    soundManager.play('helloWorld');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте тег [audio](http://htmlbook.ru/html/audio). Из минусов - это относится к HTML 5.
Есть еще варианты, но для этого конкретизируйте задачу.

Comment: Ну, мне желательно исходник, любого интерфейса, с помощью которого можно музон запускать со страницы, который можно на страницу закинуть. Если варианта получения исходника нету, то посоветуйте что-нибудь... плз

Comment: Тогда вам по [ссылке][1] - выбирайте на свой вкус).

[1]: http://www.google.ru/#&q=flash+mp3+player+для+сайта

Comment: Скажем так, мне надо сдать сайт преподавателю, и надо чтоб плеер запускался без инета и музыку проигрывал с компа, тег аудио чёт не получается заставить проигрывать вообще. Браузер в норме, всё в норме, но не проигрывает, хз, что ещё может быть, есть какие-нибудь идеи, как сделать, так чтоб проигрывало с определёной папки, или хотя бы определённые файлы с компа?

Answer (score 0):

Когдато использовал SoundManager 2(надо было сделать прослушивание примеров записей), весьма приятная библиотека - рекомендую.